# Right data structure for getting data for objects inside MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, data-structures

I have the following JSON data for one of sample mongo record:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("598b53a1e4b0d3153fe5375a"),
    "_class" : "com.Request",
    "administratorComments" : "",
    "statusLog" : [
        {
            "status" : "Submitted",
            "startDate" : ISODate("2017-08-09T18:25:37.870Z"),
            "endDate" : ISODate("2017-08-10T15:40:08.495Z")
        },
        {
            "status" : "Backlogged",
            "startDate" : ISODate("2017-08-10T15:40:08.495Z"),
            "endDate" : ISODate("2017-09-15T18:18:14.241Z")
        },
        {
            "status" : "Deleted",
            "startDate" : ISODate("2017-09-15T18:18:14.241Z"),
            "endDate" : ISODate("2017-09-15T18:18:24.764Z")
        }       
    ],
    "lastChangeDate" : ISODate("2017-09-15T18:29:35.886Z"),
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2017-08-09T18:25:37.870Z")
}
```

I am fetching the different status inside statusLog for different `_id` using a `Hashmap`:

```
HashMap<String, List<String>> hm_mongo = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

Where I am storing `_id` as Key and different status in an `Array<List>`.

Now, I am supposed to capture the `endDate` for all the status.

Could you point any data structure that will be helpful to capture the status and its `endDate` for different `_id`s for MongoDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply expand your current HashMap's value structure. In order to do this, you can create a class that will store the "status", "startDate", "endDate" fields.

```
class statusLog{
  public string status;
  public Date startDate;
  public Date endDate;
}

HashMap<String, List<statusLog>> hm_mongo = new HashMap<String, List<statusLog>>();
```